# Multiple error messages in vim message history

Tags: vim

I am trying to maintain an error message chain by passing start-up time errors to vim's error control system. For that I have the following function in my .vimrc:

```
" Local error message function
function! LocalError(err)
    " Update the errorMessageString
    let g:errorMessageString = a:err
    autocmd VimEnter * echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg g:errorMessageString | echohl None
endfunction
```

So this function is accessible down the stream, by any other scripts that are being sourced. So each one of those calls this function with a slightly different message string.

However once I display those in vim with the :messages command I able to see the multiple lines of message strings but all of them are identical.

As if the message buffer is always being overwritten by the last string that has been provided to the function. What I am doing wrong?

Here is what it should look like:

```
<banana> (SEVERE_ERROR): Unable to access.
<foo>    (SEVERE_ERROR): Unable to access.
```

However it looks like this:

```
<foo>    (SEVERE_ERROR): Unable to access.
<foo>    (SEVERE_ERROR): Unable to access.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "Here is how it looks like" vs. "However it looks like" ?? care to clarify?

Comment: Apologies, a typo there. Edited in order to make it clear. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the global `g:errorMessageString` variable is overwritten on each function invocation, but the defined `:autocmd`s will execute only later, using the then current value of the global variable.

One way to fix this is to evaluate the variable's *contents* into the `:autocmd` via `:execute`:

```
execute 'autocmd VimEnter * echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg' string(g:errorMessageString) '| echohl None'
```

#### Alternative

Or you could define `g:errorMessageString` as a *List*, append the function argument on each invocation, and define the `:autocmd` only once, but then have it `:echomsg` over all List elements.

Comment: Ah! Great! The scope, I totally messed up there. Now it works. I ued the "execute", should do it for now. Although the "list" method seems to be cleaner. Thank you very much!